# PHPExcel - Delete rows with 0 in a specific column

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have a problem with my code, basically i'm trying to find 0 in a column and delete the containing row. The code will break once found empty row (last row)

```
while(true)
{
    $value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('L'.$i++)->getValue();
    if($value == '' || $value == NULL)
        break;
    else if($value == "0" || $value == 0)
    {
        $i-=1;
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($i);
    }
}
```

The problem is that it's (apparently) not doing anything

Comment: you should use `===` instead of `==` since you are looking for specific types of values. Also, for readability reasons, you shouldn't use `$i++` in getCell... Then, don't you see anything in logs ? it should help...

Comment: Sorry for that, i just did some tests, it seems that it doesn't see the cell value as number but as text, by removing " || $value == 0 " it finally started working. Thanks!